# using read_excel with global macro

Tags: r, macros

I'm a new R user and long time Stata user and I want to use what we call in Stata global macros. I'm writing a script to automate monthly reports so I want to set the root path, folder, and file name, allowing my to change file name every month and folder every year. The file name will be the Month and Year and will also be used throughout the script in labeling graphs etc.

I've tried using read.table and read_excel without success.

I set my globals like this:

```
path <- "pathway"
folder_year <- "folder name"
month <- "month"
```

I've tried setting the data set such as: 
    dataset <- ("path", "folder", "month", "file")
so that I could call it with read_excel(dataset)but I get this error:
    Error: unexpected ',' in "dataset <- ("path","

I've tried

> myfile <- read_excel(path, folder, month_file, file)
>       Error: Unknown format .

With these I've tried different combos of commas, forward and backslash, double backslach, etc.

I know I can just copy/paste the new pathway each time but I want to make this as easy as possible for whoever takes over this project after me, with as few moving parts as possible

Comment: You probably want ```file.path``` to wrap that.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your file is named `June_2017.xlsx` and is placed inside the folder `MyFolder` at the root path `c:/Users/Me/`.
A simple R code for loading your file is:

```
library(readxl)

path <- "C:/Users/Me/"
folder <- "MyFolder"
month <- "June"
year <- "2017"

# Create the path to the file
( file_data <- paste(path,folder,"/",month,"_",year,".xlsx",sep="") )
# [1] "C:/Users/Me/MyFolder/June_2017.xlsx"

read_excel(path=file_data, sheet=1)
```

Hope it can help you.